# Como hacer una a una tabla pivote con restricción de dos tablas? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, modelorelacional

Tengo una tabla usuarios, una tabla catalogo_sugerencias, una tabla que es pivote entre usuarios  y catalogo_sugerencias a la cual llamare usuarios_sugerencias y una tabla paginas.

- Tabla 1 usuarios
- tabla intermedia usuarios_sugerencias
- Tabla 2 sugerencias

la tabla uno usuarios tiene estos datos:

- usuario_id (llave primaria)
- Nombre
- correo

la tabla dos usuarios_sugerencias intermedia tiene estos datos:

- usuarios_sugerencias_id (llave primaria)
- usuario_id (llave foránea con relación la tabla usuarios)
- sugerenca_id (llave foránea con relación a la tabla sugerencias)
- sugerencia_abierta (sugerencia que no esta en el catalogo de sugerencias)

la tabla tres sugerencias tiene estos datos:

- sugerencia_id (llave primaria)
- pagina_id (llave foranea con referencia a la tabla paginas)
- sugerencia

la tabla cuatro paginas tiene estos datos:

- pagina_id
- pagina
- descripcion

Lo que busco es hacer la relación en el modelo desde sugerencias y desde usuarios

en el modelo usuarios tendría esto

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Usuarioextends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'Usuarios';

    protected $primaryKey= 'usuario_id';


    public function UsuariosSugerencias(){
       /* Aquí es donde no se como hacer la relación quiero cuando haga esta 
         relación. Solo tengo al usuario y se que podría usar hasMany 
         para obtener todos los registros de usuarios_sugerencias asociado 
         al registro usuarios, Pero no se como obtener la pagina */

    }

}
```

en el modelo sugerencias tendría esto

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Sugerencias extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'sugerencias';

    protected $primaryKey= 'sugerencia_id';


    public function SugerenciasUsuarios(){
      /* Aquí quiero algo así 
         return RespuestaContacto::where('usuario_id ', \Auth::id())
                ->where('sugerencia_id','sugerencia_id)->get();

         Lo que generaría como resultado solo los registros solo del usuario y
         respuestas. Entonces en este caso podria saber la pagina y 
         recuperar las sugerencias del usuario.

         no se como hacer esto con las relaciones con laravel. 
      */

    }

}
```

Comment: No me queda muy claro lo que pretendes hacer, ¿relaciones entre qué tablas o modelos?

Comment: En los modelos en las tablas ya las tengo echas. Quisiera poder hacer una consulta asi Pagina::where('pagina_id', 1)->frist()->RespuestaContacto; y que me traiga las sugerencias que se le hicieron al usuario. Estas están guardadas en la tabla pivote.